# 最小量指定子 {n}? の使いどころ

Tags: .net, perl, 正規表現

Perlや.NETの正規表現には`{n}?`という最小量指定子が存在しますが、これはどのような場面で利用されるのでしょうか。

Comment: `{n}?` じゃなくて `{n,}?` の間違いではないでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/8dd5378cb01c877e1f7b#2-15

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)にもオライリーの「詳説　正規表現」にも`{n,}?`とは別に`{n}?`という最小量指定子が載っています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{n} と {n}? は同じで、他の量指定子と対称にするために存在していると思います。

Answer (score 2):

単なる冗長な表記であって `{n}` と等価です。

Perl のマニュアル (perlre) より:

> `{n}?` Match exactly n times, not greedily (**redundant**)

Answer (score 2):

正規表現の質問ですね。これは、 Ruby などにも当てはまります。

`{n}` は、 `+`, `?`, `*` などと同じように繰り返しや文字出現の表現(quantifier)であり、波括弧の中の数値で繰り返し回数の範囲を指定します。 `{最小回数, 最大回数}` で表現するところを、`{n, n}` とし、最大最小が同じことを `{n}` と表現しています。

`?` はマッチにあたっての最小量指定（言い方カッコイイ！）です。複数の一致が見られたときに最大一致のものを選択せずに、最小一致のものを選択せよという指定になります。

ここまでは理解されていると思います。

さて、実際は `?` はマッチングモードの切り替え指定です。 無指定または環境によっては `+` だと、欲張りマッチ（Greedy）でありこれがデフォルトのマッチングモードです。 `?` の指定だと、マッチングモードは、怠け者(Lazy)もしくはやる気なし(Reluctant)モードになります。やる気のないモードだと、繰り返しマッチ条件を１度満たした段階でそれ以上の走査を諦めます。

ですので、`{n}` の欲張りマッチだと、「指定数一致した！」と報告し、`{n}?` の怠け者マッチだと「もういいやここであきらめる」と報告する、という内部的にですが、動きに違いがでます。ただし、二つのモードの報告する内容はいつも同じになりますので、`{n}?` と指定するようなときには `?` の有無による違いはないことになります。

というわけで私の回答は、「気分的なもので、差がない」としたいですが、どうでしょうか。

```
$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b+)/;'
-> bbbbbbbb

$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b+?)/;'
-> b

$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b{4})/;'
-> bbbb

$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b{4}?)/;'
-> bbbb      # ここで ? の意味はない

$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b{4,8})/;'
-> bbbbbbbb

$ perl -e '$s="aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccc"; print $s =~ /(b{4,8}?)/;'
-> bbbb      # ここで 8 は意味がない

$ perl -e '$s="abbbcabbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc"; print $s =~ /(a.{4,}c)/;'
-> abbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc

$ perl -e '$s="abbbcabbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc"; print $s =~ /(a.{4,}c)/;'
-> abbbbc

$ perl -e '$s="abbbcabbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc"; print $s =~ /(a.+c)/;'
-> abbbcabbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc

$ perl -e '$s="abbbcabbbbcabbbbbcabbbbbbc"; print $s =~ /(a.+?c)/;'
-> abbbc
```

Comment: Rubyの場合`{n}`と`{n}?`は等価ではないようです。 http://ideone.com/t9UwOj

Comment: また、面白いなあ。Ruby のその例が、どうして結果を異にするのかは、わかりません。試したところでは、 `p /a{3}?/` での `?` は最小量指定子ではなく、「０または１回の出現」を表す `?` として扱われているような気がしました。 `p /a{0}?/` としようと、 `/a{1000}?/` としようと、空文字はおろか、適当に作った文字列にマッチしてしまいますね。

Answer (score 2):

Perl 5.18.2 のソースコードを眺めてみました。quantifier を処理しているのは `regcomp.c` にある `S_regpiece` 関数です。そこにこんなコメントがありました。

```
- regpiece - something followed by possible [*+?]
*
* Note that the branching code sequences used for ? and the general cases
* of * and + are somewhat optimized:  they use the same NOTHING node as
* both the endmarker for their branch list and the body of the last branch.
* It might seem that this node could be dispensed with entirely, but the
* endmarker role is not redundant.
```

Perl の開発者が regexp 用のスキャナを作る上では役に立っているのでしょうかね、、？

ところで、この関数を眺めてみると、Perl では、

```
{n} {n}? {n}+
```

は全て同じ正規表現なのですね(まぁ、ドキュメントに書いてありますね)。ところが、`{n}*` 形式はエラーとして処理しています。

```
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){2}//"
I am cold.
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){2}?//"
I am cold.
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){2}+//"
I am cold.
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){2}*//"
Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(v.*y ){2}* ...
```

これは `{n,m}*` 形式でもエラーになります。

話は脱線しますが、先の関数では `{,m}` として `n` を省略すると `{0,m}` として処理されます。これはワーニングも出ませんし、エラーにもなりません。0回のマッチングで処理されて、入力文字列はそのまま表示されます。`*` を付けてもエラーになりません。

```
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){,2}//"
I am very very cold.
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){0,2}//"
I am very very cold.
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){,2}*//"
I am very very cold.
```

一方、`n > m` で指定するとエラーメッセージが表示されます。処理は行われず、入力データはそのままです。

```
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){2,1}//"
Quantifier {n,m} with n > m can't match in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(v.*y ){2,1} ...
I am very very cold.
```

ところで、ブレースの中に整数値以外を入れるとどうなるのでしょうか。

```
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){very very cold}//"
I am very very cold.
```

これも何も起きません。これは `{0,0}` となってしまい、処理はスキップされて次の処理が実行されます。

```
$ printf "I am very very cold.\n" | perl -w -pe "s/(v.*y ){very very cold}//;s/cold/sleepy/;"
I am very very sleepy.
```

`{}` や `{,}` などでも同様で、Perl で想定している形式以外は一部を除いて(n>mなど)静かに無視されてしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

`{n}`と`{n}?`が同じ動作をするというのは他の方達が説明している通りで、
.NETでは以下のページに量指定子の説明があります。

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#quantifiers

どのような場面で使用するのかということですが、
これは上のページにもあるとおり、直前の要素とちょうど `n` 回一致するものを取得したい場合に使用します。

たとえばC#であれば、以下のようなコードが書けると思います(実用的かどうかは別の話ですが)。

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("123123123", "(123){2}");
Debug.Assert(matches.Count == 1);
Debug.Assert(matches[0].Index == 0);
Debug.Assert(matches[0].Length == 6);

var line = "      半角スペースでインデントされた行"; // 半角スペース6文字
var match = Regex.Match(line, " {4}");
Debug.Assert(match.Success);

var newline = line.Substring(match.Index + match.Length);
Debug.Assert(newline == "  半角スペースでインデントされた行"); // 半角スペース2文字
```